# How to find a header eq position with contains in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a table, and i need to know the position of header with eq() while contains the word 'this' and then, addclass to the  tag in the same row.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Header1</th>
        <th>Header2this</th> //catch you in 1
        <th>Header3this</th> //catch you in 2
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row1</td>
        <td>Row1</td> //Add class
        <td>Row1</td> //Add class
    </tr>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you show your effort

Comment: What do you mean by the "position" of the header?

Comment: @putvande you don't need comment this :) keep show us your effort

Comment: What do you mean? You just showed your HTML, but not any effort in resolving your own issue.

Comment: @putvande how can you know if im not put effort only cuz i dont paste my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty simple once you break it down into parts:

First, you need to find all the `th` elements that have 'this' in the text:

```
$('#sometable').find("th").filter(function () {
    return $(this).text().indexOf('this') > 0;
})
```

Then, for each of those, you need to figure out their index positions and add a class to the td whose index is equal to it:

```
.each(function() {
    var $table = $('#sometable');
    $table.find('td').eq($table.find("th").index(this)).addClass('class');
});
```

So, putting it all together:

```
$('#sometable').find("th").filter(function () {
    return $(this).text().indexOf('this') > 0;
}).each(function() {
    var $table = $('#sometable');
    $table.find('td').eq($table.find("th").index(this)).addClass('class');
});
```

And a [fiddle for demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5eRDG/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use indexOf() to see if a variable contains the specified string.

```
var text = $(this).text();
if (text.indexOf("this") != -1) {
```

And you can add the class to every x rows using:

```
:nth-child(3n+1)
```

Here's a working version:
http://jsfiddle.net/y69Zm/